# How to get two arrays values within one foreach()

Tags: php, foreach

There are two values I want to get from user that is name and price. I have made an auto generating rows function that generate input boxes with same name. Now the thing is I want to store them in database. I using foreach but that only get one array. I want to store both name as well as price. How can I do that. Here is my code.

HTML Form

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name[]" /><input type="text" name="price[]" />
    <input type="text" name="name[]" /><input type="text" name="price[]" />
    <input type="text" name="name[]" /><input type="text" name="price[]" />
    <input type="text" name="name[]" /><input type="text" name="price[]" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

PHP Code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    foreach($_POST['name'] as $name)
    {
        echo $name;
    }
}
```

Comment: All current answers would work, so take your pick and accept one of them that suits you particular preferences

Answer (score 2):

Call the index in the loop as well and then select the corresponding value from the other array.

```
foreach($_POST['name'] as $id => $name)
{
    echo $name;
    echo $_POST['price'][$id]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $names = $_POST['name']; # array
    $prices = $_POST['price']; # array

    foreach($names  as $id => $name)
    {
        echo $name;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $prices[$id]
    }
}
```

Comment: @Abdullah Check this

Answer (score 1):

Provided you know both arrays will be the same length, a simple for loop will do:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && count($_POST['name']) == count($_POST['price']))
{
    for($i=0; $i < count($_POST['name']); $i++)
    {
        echo $_POST['name'][$i] . ' ' . $_POST['price'][$i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$names = array_combine($_POST['name'], $_POST['price']);
foreach($names as $firstname => $price) {
  echo $firstname . ' ' . $price . '<br>';
}
```